# неожиданно перестал работать BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, broadcast-receiver

Добрый день. Настроил BroadcastReceiver в приложении, но спустя пару дней он перестал работать на устройстве Asus Zenfone 2, при этот на виртуальном устройстве все прекрасно работает.

```
public class TestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("OLOLO", "Received!!!");
    }
```

В списке задача видна

```
adb shell dumpsys alarm
Batch{24a04b21 num=8 start=25890261 end=26084096}:
RTC_WAKEUP #7: Alarm{2baa3b46 type 0 when 1459344120226 com.test.daily}
tag=*walarm*:com.test.daily/.alarm.TestReceiver
type=0 whenElapsed=+58m18s890ms when=2016-03-30 22:22:00
window=-1 repeatInterval=0 count=0
operation=PendingIntent{13aec107: PendingIntentRecord{32a28234 com.test.daily broadcastIntent}}
isUltraPowerSavingApp=false
callingUid=10184
wakeup=true
isNotAffectByListAlarm=false

+13ms 4 wakes 4 alarms: *walarm*:com.test.daily/.alarm.TestReceiver
```

Manifest:

```
<application>
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<receiver android:name=".alarm.TestReceiver"
    android:process=":remote" />
</application>
```

Comment: Может быть девайс ребутали?

Comment: ребутал, добавлял аларм по новой - ничего не помогает. при наступлении заданного времени меняется строка +13ms 4 wakes 4 alarms: *walarm*:com.test.daily/.alarm.TestReceiver, но сам ресивер не срабатывает

Comment: а покажите как регистрируете pendingIntent

Answer (score 3):

Разобрался - оказывается, в менеджере автозапуска на телефоне (раздел энергопотребление) нужно было добавить приложение в разрешенные. Раньше его там точно не было, возможно проблема появилась после какого-то обновления телефона или приложений.